# Directly pass struct to method with matching keyword arguments

Tags: ruby

As the title suggests, I'm attempting to pass a struct to a method with keyword arguments. As ruby is generally pretty terse, I was hoping there is a less verbose method of implementing what I have thus far.

Here is the class that I'm working with

```rb
class WheelStore
  attr_reader :wheels

  def initialize(data: [])
    @wheels = wheelify data
  end

  def diameters
    wheels.map { |wheel| diameter rim: wheel.rim, tire: wheel.tire }
  end

  private

  def diameter(rim:, tire:)
    rim + (tire * 2)
  end

  Wheel = Struct.new :rim, :tire, keyword_init: true
  def wheelify(data)
    data.map { |item| Wheel.new rim: item[0], tire: item[1] }
  end
end

puts WheelStore.new(data: [[10, 2], [3, 2]]).diameters
```

The question is with regards to the `diameter` method which expects a `rim` and a `tire`. I'd like for the caller to be able to just pass the `wheel`, which is a Wheel struct that implements `rim` & `tire`, to the `diameter` method.

```rb
# verbose
def diameters
  wheels.map { |wheel| diameter rim: wheel.rim, tire: wheel.tire }
end
```

```rb
#better
def diameters
  wheels.map { |wheel| diameter wheel }
end
```

```rb
#best
def diameters
  wheels.map { diameter }
end
```

I'm curious, is it just a language construct for why we can't implement the last 2 versions of this `diameters` method?

For reference, I do a lot of Javascript development and what I'm attempting here is very similar to Javascript's [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `WheelStore` is doing procedural work for `Wheel`. You need a proper Wheel class.

```
class Wheel
  attr_reader :rim, :tire

  def initialize(rim:, tire:)
    @rim = rim
    @tire = tire
  end

  def diameter
    rim + (tire * 2)
  end
end
```

Then `wheelify` goes away. Instead, use `Wheel.new` directly. Only initialize with proper Wheel objects. This is more flexible and efficient. Instead of first transforming the data from the original format into your Array of Arrays format and then again into key/value pairs, it only has to be transformed once into key/value pairs.

```
class WheelStore
  attr_reader :wheels

  def initialize(wheels: [])
    @wheels = wheels
  end

  def diameters
    wheels.map { |wheel| wheel.diameter }
  end
end

datum = [["rim1", "tire1"], ["rim2", "tire2"]]
wheel_store1 = WheelStore.new(
  wheels: datum.map { |data| Wheel.new(rim: data[0], tire: data[1]) }
)

datum = [
  { rim: "rim1", tire: "tire1" },
  { rim: "rim2", tire: "tire2" }
]
wheel_store2 = WheelStore.new(
  wheels: datum.map { |data| Wheel.new(**data) }
)
```

If you have specific data formats which you commonly turn into Wheels, then you would make a class method of Wheel to deal with them.

```
class Wheel
  class << self
    def new_from_array(wheel_data)
      new(rim: wheel_data[0], tire: wheel_data[1])
    end
  end
end

datum = [["rim1", "tire1"], ["rim2", "tire2"]]
ws = WheelStore.new(
  wheels: datum.map { |data| Wheel.new_from_array(data) }
)
```

If importing Wheels gets sufficiently complex, you might write a WheelImporter.

---

You might be assuming that a Struct will be more efficient than a named class, but in Ruby it isn't. It's pretty much exactly the same in terms of performance.

```
2.6.5 :001 > Wheel = Struct.new :rim, :tire, keyword_init: true
 => Wheel(keyword_init: true) 
2.6.5 :002 > Wheel.class
 => Class
```

---

> ```
> #best
> def diameters
>   wheels.map { diameter }
> end
> ```

2.7 added [Numbered Parameters](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Numbered+parameters).

```
wheels.map { _1.diameter }
```

Prior to 2.7 you must declare the arguments.

You can hack around this with [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) and create your own implicit versions of Enumerable methods. This turns each element into the subject of the block, `self`.

```
module Enumerable
  def implied_map(&block)
    map { |a| a.instance_eval(&block) }
  end
end

[1,2,3].implied_map { to_s }       # ["1", "2", "3"]
[1,2,3].implied_map { self.to_s }  # same
```

...but don't do that. `instance_eval` is useful for writing [DSLs](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby). But making your own versions of standard methods means you're creating your own little off-shoot of Ruby that other people will need to learn.

Comment: Ruby 2.7 has implicit block arguments: `wheels.map { _1.diameter }`. Or the good old symbol to proc conversion: `wheels.map(&:diameter)`.

Comment: Added in 2.7, I see it now. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Numbered+parameters

Comment: Thanks for the references. This answer is invaluable. This is an example problem in the book Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby by Sandi Metz and I wanted to clarify some syntax constructs. I was unfortunately unable to easily find these resources. Thank you so much again.